# From where does IE picks name of PDF in IE dialog?

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, popup

when I click on perticular PDF from collection of PDF on my webpage, IE Dialog pops up with Open, Save and Save as options.

From where does that IE Dialog picks up the PDF name we clicked upon? (PDF Name is highlighted with red box)[image: PDF Name is highlighted with red box]

Comment: Isn't this simply the filename you linked to? What's wrong with this name (beside it seems to be very long)?

Comment: @Setasign - I did not linked it to dialog name. that's why I want to know how it get's linked to clicked file name

Comment: Do you have an example link?